# Can a decoupling capacitor protect against non sinusoidal spikes?

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, decoupling-capacitor, decoupling

If we have a decoupling capacitor on a 5v input, 
and suddenly the input goes up from 5v to 10v and back to 5v, 
the voltage across the capacitor will rise to 10v and then discharge through R2 down to 5v, but if R2 was a microcontroller we were trying to protect against 10v spikes
this decoupling capacitor configuration will not work.

But if this spike went down to 0v instead of stopping in 5v, thus creating a one cycle sine wave the spike would should be attenuated.

So my question is, 
Can a decoupling capacitor protect against non sinusoidal spikes ?
or maybe there's something i am missing and all spikes are sinusoidal ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQIJcG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Spikes are (almost) never sinusoidal. And any non-sinusoidal signal, can be of course decomposed to it's sinusoidal harmonics. The schematic is showing a low-pass filter rather than a decoupling cap here.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  So how can it be Filtered out  ? is decoupling about preventing an IC from high voltage or is it about taking the sudden surge and slowing it down ?

Comment: @EugeneSh., i think that you would have to design specialized circuitry if you wanted to produce a sinusoidal spike

Comment: Your description of what happens in the circuit in your question is sadly misconceived.

Comment: @EugeneSh. it's just like a capacitor between Vdd and GND, that's what i usually see in schematics, so i thought this was the same

Comment: @Andyaka you mean poorly explained ? or did i completely misunderstand  the behavior of the circuit ?

Comment: As you might know, capacitors don't "like" the voltage to be changed on them "suddenly", so the voltage on the junction point will not have any sudden spikes, even if there are some on the "5V" input.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that still doesn't mean it will not reach 10v , and if there's an IC that is sensitive to 10v, we didn't protect it. but again, i might be misunderstanding the whole decoupling thing, since a zener would be better than that capacitor for sinking anything above 5v.

Comment: Spikes are *supposed* to be short. Meaning low-energy. If the energy is low, it won't be enough to charge the capacitor up to 10V. Well, is it is not, then your circuit is not sufficient to filter such a spikes. You will need some kind of overvoltage protection.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes i know it won't filter any spike, that's what i am saying,  but all decoupling capacitors that i see are connected this way, this is why i can't see a way for it to filter any non sinusoidal spike

Comment: 10uF*100R limits voltage to 63% in 1ms and more or less depending on duration . Eg 1kV from 100pF Source on 100nF low ESR cap might be reduced to 1V.

Comment: @soundslikefiziks "all decoupling capacitors that i see are connected this way" No, they aren't. Unless you consider power wires resistance to be 100 Ohm, in which case you have _really bad wires_. And I am yet to see MCU with 1k impedance on power inputs. And 10uF is not really a typical decoupling cap value. In short - your circuit has nothing _at all_ in common with decoupling.

Comment: @Maple , ok , imagine there are no resistors in my circuit and ive any value you want to the capacitor , it still wouldn't filter any spikes unless they are sinusoidal

Comment: @soundslikefiziks There is no basis for that belief. You keep saying it but it isn't true.

Comment: @EJP it's not a belief, it's how a capacitor works, look at a half wave rectifier capacitor

Comment: The output of a half wave rectifier is not sinusoidal. Yet it gets filtered. QED. You are just making this all up. It has no basis.

Comment: @soundslikefiziks From time to time I stumble upon questions where OP does not really want an answer, only confirmation of incorrect but heavily ingrained assumptions. This is one of those.

Comment: @EJP , i know it's not sinusoidal, and the spike is not filtered, it turns into a somehow straight DC line, look :  https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/3/9/6/3/e/519a7ebfce395fde13000000.png

Comment: 'Not filtered' and 'turned into a somehow straight line' are mutually contradictory. You are just talking nonsense here.

Comment: @EJP  filters work  not just by straighting the line, but also by greatly attenuating it

Comment: So in other words a DC power supply can never possibly work? Please. You have some utterly baseless notions here. You're talking whe you should be listening. If you're not going to take any notice of what you're being told here why bother posting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A capacitor takes current when the voltage across it is rising. The formula is: -

$$I = C\cdot\dfrac{dV}{dt}$$

Where dv/dt is the rate of change of voltage applied to the capacitor. It has nothing specifically to do with sine waves - it takes current X when the rate of change of voltage multiplied by capacitance = X.

If the voltage isn't changing then no current is taken by the capacitor. If the voltage is falling then that is because current is being taken out of the capacitor.

Nothing to do with sine waves.

Rearranging the formula allows us to conclude that with a constant current into a capacitor, the rate of change of voltage is constant i.e.: -

$$\dfrac{dV}{dt} = \dfrac{I}{C}$$

So if the capacitor is very large in value, the rate of change of voltage across its terminals is smaller compared to a small value capacitor.

So, if you have a 100 ohm resistor feeding a 10 uF capacitor like this: -

[image]

And you raised the input voltage instantaneously to 10 volts from a previously steady value of 5 volts, the capacitor voltage would begin to rise (but much more slowly than the voltage change at the input). This is because the rate of change of capacitor voltage is governed by the current into the capacitor and, that is limited by the 100 ohm resistor and the change of 5 volts at the input.

The initial capacitor current is (10 volts - 5 volts)/100 ohms = 50 mA.

This means that the initial rise of capacitor voltage is 50 mA / 10 uF = 5000 volts per second. If the application of the 10 volts was a tiny glitch of duration 10 us, then the voltage on the capacitor would rise by approximately 50 mV over that 10 us. It would begin at 5 volts and rise to 5.05 volts after 10 us. If the glitch returned to a constant 5 volts after 10 us, then the capacitor voltage would return to 5 volts after about 10 us.

Hence in this scenario the capacitor has protected a 5 volt circuit from a spike of 10 volts that lasted for 10 us. If the spike lasted longer, then the approximations I used to calculate the rise in capacitor voltage start to erode and you have to consider that as the capacitor voltage rises, the current through the resistor reduces. It's simple ohms law - when the capacitor was at 5 volts and the spike was at 10 volts the current through the resistor was simply (10 - 5) volts / 100 ohms.

If the capacitor was allowed to charge to 5.5 volts (due to a longer duration spike) the current into the capacitor is now only 45 mA. If the capacitor was allowed to charge to 9 volts (due to a much longer spike) then the current into the capacitor at this point is only 10 mA.

This means that as the capacitor charges, the rate of change of voltage across its terminals reduces, hence the capacitor charges like this: -

[image]

And, although the capacitor will eventually charge to a voltage that is the magnitude of a long spike, it still offers considerable protection against short-lived or moderate spikes.

Answer (score 3):

A [Decoupling Capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling_capacitor) is usually used on power supply lines. They are relatively large, and the intention is to stop the line's voltage varying more than a very small amount. They are so-called because they decouple the effect of large changes of current drawn by one part of the circuit affecting the voltage on another part of the circuit.

What you have drawn, on an input line, is a [filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit). This is intended to allow signals through, but to slow down their edges. It will also stop short duration spikes from changing the voltage at the output significantly. This may be sufficient to protect from some transients. It depends on the enery of the transient whether the output voltage will cause the following circuit problems.

Perhaps what you need is input overvoltage protection, the simplest of which is a zener diode, or diode clamps to the rails.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJWvGj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I see, but if those spikes are on an AC , they usually have a frequency, in that case i understand how the filter works, but if they are on dc, and they don't repeat themselves, like in my example, from 5v to 10v and back to 5v,   then i fail to understand how it can attenuate anything.    
for example, a capacitor on a half wave rectifier

Comment: spikes are spikes, they have an energy, and an amplitude, and a duration, not a frequency. DC passes through filters and decoupling caps. AC passes through filters depending on the frequency, AC 'tends not' to pass through decoupling caps, unless very low frequency indeed.

Comment: i just don't see why capacitor coupling is used in dc, instead of zener diodes.   if we were talking about filters on a signal , i would completely understand, if they are used to stabilize voltage drops, i would understand, but when it comes to protecting against higher voltage, they would not block it.

Comment: Where in this answer do you see anything saying about decoupling caps protecting from high voltages?

Comment: @EugeneSh. i don't, i see the diodes doing that, but decoupling is supposed to protect an ic against that, and so far, i can only see how it work with against high frequencies (low pass filter) , but not with spikes.

Comment: A spike is by definition is a high frequency change in a signal.

Comment: *but decoupling is supposed to protect an ic against that* what makes you think that, where have you been given that idea?

Comment: @Neil_UK , i just looked at the formation of Voltage spikes here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_spike

Comment: @soundslikefiziks "but decoupling is supposed to protect an ic against that", no, you are WRONG! The main purpose of decoupling caps is to avoid the power rail voltage do drop too much if the chip draws a sudden spike of current. Even if they *may* attenuate some spikes,  they are not meant to regulate the voltage, i.e. maintaining a voltage to a preset level, or as protection elements. For that you need voltage regulators or (if you only need something for *protecting* against overvoltages) diode clamps.

Comment: @soundslikefiziks, BTW, the Wikipedia article on spikes that you link to is very low quality. It is a bunch of information crammed together with little coherence. Although many sentences are not wrong in themselves, some are utterly vague and the whole thing is poorly written, from a scientific and technical POV. BTW, note the banner in that article warning about missing sources.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati A capacitor working as a tiny power source in cases of voltage drops is something i can understand, the only thing i had a problem with were those "spikes"

Comment: @LorenzoDonati  Yes, i saw the banner now, but the drawing itself is  not correct ? i mean the formation of the spikes

Comment: @soundslikefiziks That drawing doesn't *explain* the formation of spikes. It is just an example of how spikes may be when superimposed onto an AC waveform. I repeat, it is not an *explanation*, just a visualization. Explaining *exactly* why a capacitor is not a good way to protect a chip power rail from spikes involves difficult math. The main reason is that the capacitor is a linear component, i.e. (roughly) its response is proportional to the spike. It may attenuate it, but the attenuation is the same regardless from the amplitude of the spike (assuming the same shape)....

Comment: @soundslikefiziks  ...In other words if a 10V spike is attenuated 100 times, it becomes harmeless (100mV), but a 100V spike even if attenuated results in a 1V variation of the power rail, which could be fatal for a 3.3V chip. Diodes clamps, on the other hand, are not linear, so they "attenuate more bigger spikes" (I'm oversimplifying, but I hope you get the point).

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Yes , i think i am seeing it now, i just thought it had more "voltage regulating" properties. which according to  "Andy aka"'s answer, the capacitor does attenuate spikes to some degree, but again, in a smaller range and duration than i thought.

Comment: @soundslikefiziks It *does* have voltage regulating properties, which is why your initial assertion that +10V in = +10V out is baseless.

Answer (score 1):

Lets put a spike into this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feEfJa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>